# How to get java program read it's internal path to make it work on every PC

Tags: java

I'm trying to configure path in code to my excel file to make it work on every computer that i have source code on for example:

my actual file is in com/company/resources/DatabaseLogonData.xlsx
but im trying to open it from class that is in com/company/Database/DatabaseConnection.java

I suppose i have to go back somehow to com/company and then go to the Database package but don't know how

```java
package com.company.Database;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    private static Database localDatabase;

    public static void setLocalDatabaseFromFile() 
throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(
"C:\\Users\\Wiktor\\IdeaProjects\\mixer\\src\\com\\company\\resources\\DatabaseLogonData.xlsx"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row dataRow = sheet.getRow(1);
        localDatabase = new Database(dataRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue(),
dataRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue(),
dataRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue(),
dataRow.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
    }
```

I want to get path that will work on any pc. Thanks for any feedback !

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home");` for the "C:\\Users\\{userName}" part?

Comment: Please, reformat your source code to remove the horizontal scrollbar. The removing increases the readability.

Comment: Okay that's helpfull but still it's not automatic at all because someone can have it in IdeaProject but there can be someone that have in Desktop

Comment: Consider using the `resources` mechanism, check this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/classloader_getresource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.nio` in order to find out where the code is executed:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Path cwd = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();
    Path parentOfCwd = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().getParent();
    System.out.println(cwd.toAbsolutePath().toString() 
            + " in folder " + parentOfCwd.toAbsolutePath().toString());
}
```

I don't know if this is best practice for your use case, but you could as well go the way many programs are going and just determine the `user.home` (see comments below your question), create a folder and store the logs there.

Comment: It's not quite what i've meant but method toAbsolutePath() got me the anwser which is :```public static String getExcelPath(){
        File file = new File("com/company/resources/DatabaseLogonData.xlsx");
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }```

Comment: At least a little helpful this answer ;-)